# React project development without page refresh

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dom, jsx, refresh

I have two React project I work on but the development feels very different because of this aspect.

One of them doesn't refresh the whole browser page when making a change in its JSX, but the change is still rendered into DOM, like it happens when updating a style file.

It's much more comfortable this way, especially when working with multiple sub-components that needs to be opened in order to see the result.

It wasn't always like that, only since several months ago, when I think I updated some packages... but can't figure out what really happened.

Is there a setting that can be made to get this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: You have different configuration for each project

Comment: But what configuration does that?

Comment: Webpack probably, depends on what build you are using. You didn't specify so I guess that `create-react-app` which uses `webpack`